# Using Bootstrap Glyph icons in iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, itext, glyphicons

I am building a .NET/C#/MVC system that uses Bootstrap and iTextSharp.

I have two Glyph font icons that I would also like to use when generating a PDF document using iTextSharp.

The only way I know to include and image in a PDF, is to designate a stream to an image:

```
 Stream imageStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Onlineeksamen.Web.Resources.ios7-phone1-icon.png");
 Image image = Image.GetInstance(imageStream);
```

The Glyph icons are available in following files:

```
fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

I now have following sample based on the comment from jme but it doesnt work - I assume that the icons are characters in the font:

```
outputStream = new MemoryStream();
document = new Document(PageSize.A4, margin, margin, margin, margin);
pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputStream);
document.Open();
pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.DirectContent;
PageHeight = document.PageSize.Height;
pdfContentByte.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);

string fontFile = String.Format("{0}fonts\\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf", HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath);
BaseFont customfont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontFile, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(customfont, 12);
pdfContentByte.BeginText();

pdfContentByte.SetTextMatrix(100, PageHeight.Value - 100);
pdfContentByte.ShowText("This should be glyphs");
pdfContentByte.EndText();

document.Close();
return outputStream.ToArray();
```

Thank you in advance

Soeren D.

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/81/iTextSharp-Working-with-Fonts  See the example for registering fonts at the end of the article.

Comment: Hi, I tried to follow the example and I think it registers the font correctly - but when I use it I get squares instead of GlyphIcons.

I should mention that I use BaseFonts instead of Fonts because I write directly to the PdfContentByte object.

Comment: You'll need to post a small example of how you are using the fonts as well as how you are parsing the HTML and CSS. Try to boil the HTML and CSS down to as few lines as possible. iText will only use the TTF files so you can also ignore the others, too. I'm a little confused, however, when you say that you're writing directly to the `PdfContentByte` object. Did you build your own parser then? I ask because if you feel comfortable with the `PdfContentByte`, using HTML as the middle man seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: Hi Chris, I dont try to parse HTML. I use PdfContentByte to write PDF and simply wants to use some icons from bootstrap Glyphicons.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the way that you tagged this. The font that you are using has no Latin glyph code-points, only the private use E001 through E200. If you go to the [source site](http://glyphicons.com/), click on "Halfings" and hover over each you'll see the code point that you need for that specific glyph. Any glyph not listed there, including letters and punctuation like periods and commas, will not work. That said, when I embed that specific font I cannot seem to get it to render anything in the PDF.

Comment: Now I get it :) I cannot find a listing of the character set from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) on [glyphicons.com](http://glyphicons.com), so I cannot get the hexcode. I tried guessing from the bootstrap css file and thus `pdfContentByte.ShowText(String.Format("{0} {1}", "\xE025", "\xE026"));` should yield a download icon but it doesn't.